# RavenDB: how to delete/remove duplicate entities?

Tags: c#, .net, json, database, ravendb

My question is above, how to delete/remove duplicates in RavenDB?
I cheked this link [How to remove duplicate entities in the objectstatemanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158865/how-to-remove-duplicate-entities-in-the-objectstatemanager)
But that link is not what I want.
Any idea?

Comment: The link you provided is only to be used when you query the database, make changes, and then try to check-in to database the changes.  In your case you are only trying to remove duplicates without a query.  So you need to group the rows.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409769/ravendb-mapreduce-grouping-by-multiple-fields

Comment: How do you define a duplicate? Duplicate user names? Duplicate IDs? Duplicate properties?

Comment: Why do you let duplicates to be created in the first place? You could use the unique constraints bundle to prevent them from being created.